# Why are these wildcards not working in Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards

I'm having this issue on Word 2016. I can't use the wildcards that I was working with on other versions.

What may be the issue here?

[image]

Comment: On my Windows with German region settings & Word, I have to use `{1;100}`. Did you construct the pattern manually or by using the templates from the “Special” button?

Comment: @DanielB I created it manually on another computer. Even after changing the comma for the semicolon it still doesn't work...

Comment: Add your specific 'find' query as a code block to your question to make testing easier